# Pass parameter from Jquery to webhandler asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to be able to drag and drop files into multiple folders on a server, I am using jquery to pass to HttpHandler but I can't pass the save location to webhandler. I would like to send the path from jquery in the request is there a way to incluse that when the data for file transfer is passed.

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FileHandler.ashx",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was error uploading files!");
            }
        });
```

Maybe something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "FileHandler.ashx",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            filepath: document.getElementById("<%=listDrop.ClientID%>");
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was error uploading files!");
            }
        });
```

and then retrieve the path in the webhandler to pass as save location?

I have tried this `$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FileHandler.ashx",
                contentType:false,
                processData: false,
                data: {
                    data: newData,
                    filepath:JSON.stringify("~/uploads/")
                },

                success: function (result) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("There was error uploading files!");
                }
            });` But I have question about the declaration of the data type for the files I will be uploading when creating the get and set in asp. filepath is a string but what data type are the files.

Answer (score 0):

although i am answering from my mobile, i tried my best to keep the things intact and use ful. If required, Please format it accordingly.
I am not going to write entire code here, just algo.
1. Identify the parameter to be passed. If its only path of multiple folders then you can create an array of objects in javascript  for the same. See tge example
var listOfFolder = new string[];
listOfFolder[0]="path of first dir";
:
:
listOfFolder[n]="path of nth dir";
var data = JSON.stringify(listOfFolder);
2. pass this data in data attribute of jquery ajax. 3. Grab this path in Process Request event and deserialize.
4. Do whatever you want.